# How to fetch an array object from API json file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have a JSON data and I would like to render only name from there.

With `${data.people}`, I can see:

> {"name": "Neil Alden Armstrong", "craft": "ISS"}

but I would like to get only names: "Neil Alden Armstrong"

I've tried `${data.people.name}` or `{data.name}` but both returned undefined.
How can I get name?

JSON data

```json
{
  "message": "success", 
  "people": 
    [
      {"name": "Neil Alden Armstrong", "craft": "ISS"}, 
      {"name": "Buzz Aldrin", "craft": "ISS"}, 
      {"name": "Sally Kristen Ride", "craft": "ISS"}
    ], 
  "number": 3
}
```

js file

```js
const contentTag = document.getElementById('content');
fetch(' here is the url of json data ')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)

    const jsonToString = JSON.stringify(data.people);
    console.log('jsonToString', jsonToString);

    contentTag.textContent = `
    There are ${data.number} astronauts in space, they are:
    ${JSON.stringify(data.people)}
    `;
    console.log("name", data.peolpe);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`people` is an array of three objects. You'll need to loop through each to grab the names. You can use `array.map()` to convert an array of people to an array of names:

```
const names = data.people.map(p => p.name) // Neil..., Buzz..., Sally...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract only the `name` of each person :

```
JSON.stringify( data.people.map( person => person.name) )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `people` is an array of objects. You have to iterate though them like for example

```
data.people.forEach((person) => console.log(person.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the name you need to access on the array then access the object

```js
console.log(data.people[0].name) // Neil Alden Armstrong
console.log(data.people[1].name) // Buzz Aldrin
console.log(data.people[2].name) // Sally Kristen Ride
```

or you can loop through the array